# How do you convert an array of strings to an array of hashes?

Tags: ruby, string, csv, methods, hash

An array of two strings follows. I would like to know how to convert it to an array of two hashes.

```
["{:date=>\"11/24/13 12:39 PM\", :gross_profit=>32.5, :cogs=>9.75, :net_profit=>38.5, :units_sold=>5}",
   "{:date=>\"11/24/13 12:41 PM\", :gross_profit=>29.5, :cogs=>8.9, :net_profit=>34.2, :units_sold=>4}"]
```

I took a different route and saved the csv file in a different format which allowed me to more easily manipulate the data in my ruby file so this question no longer needs to be open.

Comment: Give us proper data..

Comment: You can't. That will not be accepted by Ruby parser.

Comment: That's not CSV. Nor is it JSON. Where did you get it, and what code did you write to try to solve this question?

Comment: I assume it's intended to be an array of two strings, which s_jw wants converted to hashes, in which case one open bracket and two closed brackets should be removed.  With that done, there's nothing wrong with the question.  s_jw, I suggest you edit to avoid attracting additional downvotes.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks for the tip. That was copy and pasted from my IRB, not sure if that has anything to do with it. I'm a beginner so it's hard to tell where and why things are formatted the way that they are and whether it's correct or needs to be edited.

Comment: Why haven't you edited your question?  Put just one open bracket `[` at the beginning and just one closed bracket `]` at the end and you are good to go.  If I may suggest wording: "An array of two strings follows.  I would like to know how to convert it to an array of two hashes."

Comment: Was caught up with a few other things, changes now made. Thanks again for your help, at this point I recognize your name and know you've helped me with several other questions as well. Much appreciated.

Comment: @theTinMan please see edits. I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing one bracket from the beginning of the array and two from the end:

```
a = ["{:date=>\"11/24/13 12:39 PM\", :gross_profit=>32.5, :cogs=>9.75, \
       :net_profit=>38.5, :units_sold=>5}", \
     "{:date=>\"11/24/13 12:41 PM\", :gross_profit=>29.5, :cogs=>8.9, \
       :net_profit=>34.2, :units_sold=>4}"]

a.map {|s| s.sub("{","").sub("}","").gsub(":","").gsub(/\"/,"").split(',')}.map {|e| \
    e.map {|f|k, v = f.strip.split("=>");[k.to_sym, v]}}.map {|e| Hash[*e.flatten]}

 # => [{:date=>"11/24/13 1239 PM", :gross_profit=>"32.5", :cogs=>"9.75",
        :net_profit=>"38.5", :units_sold=>"5"},
       {:date=>"11/24/13 1241 PM", :gross_profit=>"29.5", :cogs=>"8.9",
        :net_profit=>"34.2", :units_sold=>"4"}]
```

Let's break this down:

```
b = a.map {|s| s.sub("{","").sub("}","").gsub(":","").gsub(/\"/,"").split(',')}
  # => [["date=>"11/24/13 1239 PM", " gross_profit=>32.5", " cogs=>9.75", \
         " net_profit=>38.5", " units_sold=>5"], \
        ["date=>"11/24/13 1241 PM", " gross_profit=>29.5", " cogs=>8.9", \
         " net_profit=>34.2", " units_sold=>4"]]

    c = b.map {|e| e.map {|f|k, v = f.strip.split("=>");[k.to_sym, v]}}
      # => [[[:date, "11/24/13 1239 PM"], [:gross_profit, "32.5"], [:cogs, "9.75"], \
             [:net_profit, "38.5"], [:units_sold, "5"]], \
            [[:date, "11/24/13 1241 PM"], [:gross_profit, "29.5"], [:cogs, "8.9"], \
             [:net_profit, "34.2"], [:units_sold, "4"]]]

        c.map {|e| Hash[*e.flatten]} # => result above
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to start by removing the unbalanced right bracket, then call `eval` on both strings to return them to hashes:

```
2.0.0p247 :010 > arr = [["{:date=>\"11/24/13 12:39 PM\", :gross_profit=>32.5, :cogs=>9.75, :net_profit=>38.5, :units_sold=>5}",
2.0.0p247 :011 >          "{:date=>\"11/24/13 12:41 PM\", :gross_profit=>29.5, :cogs=>8.9, :net_profit=>34.2, :units_sold=>4}"]]
 => [["{:date=>\"11/24/13 12:39 PM\", :gross_profit=>32.5, :cogs=>9.75, :net_profit=>38.5, :units_sold=>5}", "{:date=>\"11/24/13 12:41 PM\", :gross_profit=>29.5, :cogs=>8.9, :net_profit=>34.2, :units_sold=>4}"]] 

2.0.0p247 :013 > hash1, hash2 = arr.flatten.map {|str| eval(str)}
 => [{:date=>"11/24/13 12:39 PM", :gross_profit=>32.5, :cogs=>9.75, :net_profit=>38.5, :units_sold=>5}, {:date=>"11/24/13 12:41 PM", :gross_profit=>29.5, :cogs=>8.9, :net_profit=>34.2, :units_sold=>4}] 

2.0.0p247 :014 > hash1
 => {:date=>"11/24/13 12:39 PM", :gross_profit=>32.5, :cogs=>9.75, :net_profit=>38.5, :units_sold=>5} 

2.0.0p247 :015 > hash2
 => {:date=>"11/24/13 12:41 PM", :gross_profit=>29.5, :cogs=>8.9, :net_profit=>34.2, :units_sold=>4}
```

Comment: That's rather cool, a good example of using `eval` to advantage.  `eval` fearmongers: take heed!